# Unable to use helper classes within unit tests of a bundled aurelia app. RequireJS Configuration?

Tags: requirejs, aurelia

**Summary**

Using the aurelia cli and the default tasks that are included, I am unable to leverage helper classes that are located within the test folder in my unit tests.

**Details**

Starting with the sample app created with au new, I have a contrived helper class located within 'test/util/helper.ts':

```js
export class Helper {
    Property : string;
}
```

This class is imported by the test/unit/app.spec.ts file:

```js
import {App} from '../../src/app';
import {Helper} from "../util/helper";

describe('the app', () => {
  it('says hello', () => {
    let h = new Helper();
    h.Property = "Testing";
    expect(h.Property).toBe("Testing");
    expect(new App().message).toBe('Hello World!');
  });
});
```

**Approach #1 - Bundling**
I have modified the aurelia.json file in a few places:

- Change the source of the typescript compiler to include files under the test folder

  ```
  "transpiler": {
     "id": "typescript",
     "displayName": "TypeScript",
     "fileExtension": ".ts",
     "dtsSource": [
       "./typings/**/*.d.ts",
       "./custom_typings/**/*.d.ts"
     ],
     "source": ["src\\**\\*.ts","test\\**\\*.ts"]
  },
  ```
- Modify the app-bundle to exclude any file from the test folder

  ```
    {
      "name": "app-bundle.js",
      "source": {
        "include": [
          "[**/*.js]",
          "**/*.{css,html}"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/test/**/*"
        ]
      }
    },
  ```
- Add a new bundle (test-util-bundle), which includes files from the test\util folder and excludes files within the src and test/unit folders

  ```
  {
    "name": "test-util-bundle.js",
    "source": {
      "include": [
        "[**/*.js]"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "**/src/**/*",
        "**/test/unit/**/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  ```

After bundling the app with 'au build', I have three bundles (app/vendor/test-util), with the test-util-bundle.js bundle defining the helper class like this:

```
define('../test/util/helper',["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var Helper = (function () {
        function Helper() {
        }
        return Helper;
    }());
    exports.Helper = Helper;
});
```

I suspect this is the root of the problem, but not that familiar with RequireJS.

When I do run 'au test' the test fails with the following error:

```
11 10 2016 12:05:24.606:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/git/aurelia-cli-testing/test/test/util/helper
11 10 2016 12:05:24.608:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/test/test/util/helper
Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
Uncaught Error: Script error for "C:/git/aurelia-cli-testing/test/test/util/helper", needed by: C:/git/aurelia-cli-testing/test/util/helper
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
at C:/git/aurelia-cli-testing/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3763
```

**Note:**
This works fine if I move the helper.ts file under the src tree (as done [here](http://www.jujens.eu/posts/en/2016/Aug/17/switch-to-aurelia-cli/)).  This is all available [here](https://github.com/ChrisMancini/aurelia-cli-testing) if you would like to see the behavior.

**Approach #2 - Without Bundling of utility class**

- Modify karma.conf.js

```
    let testSrc = [
      { pattern: project.unitTestRunner.source, included: false },
      { pattern: "test/util/**/*.ts", included: false },
      'test/aurelia-karma.js'
    ];

    ...

    preprocessors: {
      [project.unitTestRunner.source]: [project.transpiler.id],
      ["test/util/**/*.ts"]: [project.transpiler.id]
    },
```

With this modification (no bundling of the utility class) karma produces the following error:

```
18 10 2016 16:56:59.151:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/git/aurelia-cli-testing/test/util/helper
18 10 2016 16:56:59.152:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/test/util/helper
Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: Script error for "C:/git/aurelia-cli-testing/test/util/helper", needed by: C:/git/aurelia-cli-testing/test/unit/app.spec.js
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
  at C:/git/aurelia-cli-testing/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:3763
```

Thanks for reading, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using karma as your test runner?  If so did you add the new file location to your karma config?

Comment: I am using the karma test runner.  The karma.conf.js file remains the original file generated from the 'au new' command.

Looking at the file, I am not quite sure where I would add the new file location.

The new bundle is being added to the 'files' field of the config sent to karma if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of an Aurelia team member, a small modification to the aurelia-karma.js file that is distributed with the aurelia cli fixes the issue:

The normalizePath function should be modified to append '.js' where applicable:

```
function normalizePath(path) {
  var normalized = []
  var parts = path
    .split('?')[0] // cut off GET params, used by noext requirejs plugin
    .split('/')

  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (parts[i] === '.') {
      continue
    }

    if (parts[i] === '..' && normalized.length && normalized[normalized.length - 1] !== '..') {
      normalized.pop()
      continue
    }

    normalized.push(parts[i])
  }

  //Use case of testing source code. RequireJS doesn't add .js extension to files asked via sibling selector
  //If normalized path doesn't include some type of extension, add the .js to it
  if(normalized.length > 0 && normalized[normalized.length-1].indexOf('.') < 0){
    normalized[normalized.length-1] = normalized[normalized.length-1] + '.js';
  }

  return normalized.join('/')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to do the following:
1. update the aurelia-project/aurelia.json file.  add this

> ```
>   "unitTestRunnerUtils": {
> "id": "karmaUtils",
> "displayName": "Karma",
> "source": "test\\utils\\**\\*.js"   },
> ```

Then in the karma.conf.js file updated these two places.

> let testSrc = [   { pattern: project.unitTestRunner.source, included:
>   false },   { pattern: project.unitTestRunnerUtils.source, included:
>   false},   'test/aurelia-karma.js' ];

and

> preprocessors: {
>         [project.unitTestRunner.source]: [project.transpiler.id],
>         [project.unitTestRunnerUtils.source]: [project.transpiler.id]
>       },

And then it worked...

Here is the example project on github.

https://github.com/duranmg/demo-aurelia-testing

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike...

I think that translates to my "Approach #2".  Do you have a sample repository that I can look at?

Comment: no i just used the aurelia-cli and created a new app and then added the code above

Comment: I just started with a brand new app via the aurelia-cli and made the same modifications you did, however I received the same error as before.

Did you modify the app.spec file to require the file within the utils folder?

Comment: I updated the post with the url to my demo project on github